# Carbon loop through specific date range misses one day

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, laravel-5, php-carbon

**SOLUTION :**

```
 $mDatePeriod = new \DatePeriod(

          Carbon::parse("First Monday of January 2018"),
          CarbonInterval::week(),
          Carbon::parse("Last Monday of January 2018")->addSecond(1)
 );
```

---

I am running Laravel 5.0 and i am using Carbon library to calculate the below.

Example :

I want to have all **Mondays** of **January** of **2018** so i am using the below code :

```
 $mDatePeriod = new \DatePeriod(

          Carbon::parse("First Monday of January 2018"),
          CarbonInterval::week(),
          Carbon::parse("Last Monday of January 2018")
 );
```

If i loop through `$mDatePeriod` and echo the day :

```
foreach($mDatePeriod as $currentDay){

 echo $currentDay->toDateString() . "<br/>";

}
```

Output will be :

```
2018-01-01
2018-01-08
2018-01-15
2018-01-22
```

Which is not what i am expecting, because **2018-01-29** (last monday) is missing.

If i use `dd($mDatePeriod_Day)` last monday is shown as the end of the date :

[image]

What am i missing here?

EDIT 1 : Found something interesting about **CarbonInterval::week()**, which has some attributes. Could it be `first_last_day_of`? :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is added the time at the last condition

```
Carbon::parse("Last Monday of January 2018 00:00:01")
```

Then you can get the date.

Comment: I am accepting this as an answer. My final solution was to modify my `parse` like this `Carbon::parse("Last Monday of January 2018")->addSecond(1)`